# Safe to install a downloaded eclipse installation file?

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

I have been reading about the process of installing eclipse manually, so that is not my question. I just wonder if there are any real risks to system stability if I install manually instead of using the command line. I have used Juno quite a bit, so I don't want to use an older version which is available through the Ubuntu software center.

Comment: It might help for your question to say what file/script you downloaded from where. "Safeness" depends a lot on the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not safe. Running untrusted scripts from the internet is never safe. A trusted ppa (for example, from the creators of eclipse) is the preferred way.

If you run a script from the internet, make sure it comes from a trusted place. A script from askubuntu might be good, if it is for your specific OS version and if the answer is upvoted.

Comment: Thanks. I will check my settings to see if I have an Eclipse ppa.